# cmd.exe highlight background color

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, colors

When you highlight text with the Command Prompt (cmd.exe), it just inverts the
colors of whatever you selected:

> [image: white]

However the white is a little bright for me, I would prefer gray background.
Can I change the white highlight color, if so how?

http://github.com/Microsoft/console/issues/64

Comment: you could change Screen Background colour to 50,50,50. That will make it a dark grey, and so the inverse will be a light grey

Comment: Change the screen background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using Windows Terminal:

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

Example configuration:

```json
{
   "profiles": {
      "list": [{
         "commandline": "powershell.exe -NoLogo",
         "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
         "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF"
      }]
   }
}
```

Some other options here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/terminal/customize-settings/color-schemes

Answer (score 5):

The **Popup Background** settings from the **Console Windows Properties** is for the the color of the console popup window such as when you press **F7** to view the history of commands you've used in your console session.

[image]

By default the console screen highlight color simply appears to be the inverse color of whatever color you have set in the **Console Windows Properties** from the **Screen Background** setting.

[image]

Therefore as suggested, if you set the **Screen Background** colors to **50,50,50** in the **Selected Color Values** settings, then this seems to give you a gray highlight color per its inverse color.

[image]

[image]

The trade off for doing this is that the regular of non-highlighted console background color will be of a lighter shade than just solid black.

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- Consider adjusting the color, contrast and/or brightness settings of your monitor rather than the Console Windows Properties to get you a desired result of color shades, etc. too.
- [Introducing the Windows Console Colortool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/08/11/introducing-the-windows-console-colortool/)

Comment: I am sorry that I added that extraneous information - when asking a question I try to put what I have tried - to show that I am not being lazy. However in this case it backfired because you focused only on what I tried rather than what the actual question is. I have edited the question - sadly I feel your answer is no longer germane given the current edit

Comment: My answer is still relevant per the standard and default way to change exactly what you are asking about... *"cmd.exe highlight background color"* even though it's not the solution you'd like to use for that specific task in your case. For others that are able to use the suggestion in my answer, it'll do exactly what you are asking about still. It's all good in the hood though—I look forward to seeing what solution you find that suffices that's different than doing it the typical/standard way I wrote about.